# iPhone SDK - gdata oauth

Tags: iphone, oauth, gmail

I am about to build an application in iPhone which uses gmail. I am new to web application. I know a bit how to authenticate using OAuth and the process of OAuth. But I dont know where to find the OAuth libraries for gmail. Please, I need a guidance to get the OAuth for gmail. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the following link:

http://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth/